# Deploying SpringWS application on Websphere without any database component throwing Error creating bean with name defaultValidator

Tags: spring, maven, deployment, websphere, spring-ws

Hi have been trying to deploy a **SpringWS** Application onto **Websphere-8.5.5.12** application server. but It's throwing the following error. Though I understood the error but not able to solve it.

`[2/10/20 23:24:23:348 IST] 0000009d SystemErr     R com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: Failed to load webapp: Error creating bean with name &amp;#39&#59;defaultValidator&amp;#39&#59; defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/validation/ValidationAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed&amp;#59&#59; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/validation/Configuration.getDefaultParameterNameProvider&amp;#40&#59;&amp;#41&#59;Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider&amp;#59&#59; &amp;#40&#59;loaded from file:/C:/Program Files &amp;#40&#59;x86&amp;#41&#59;/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/plugins/javax.j2ee.validation.jar by org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader@20dbc652&amp;#41&#59; called from class org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean &amp;#40&#59;loaded from file:/C:/Program&amp;#37&#59;20Files&amp;#37&#59;20&amp;#40&#59;x86&amp;#41&#59;/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/installedApps/DDRFFSN2Node01Cell/Pru_FeService-1-0_0_1-SNAPSHOT_war.ear/Pru_FeService-1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar by 
com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader@b09dd62[war:Pru_FeService-1-0_0_1-SNAPSHOT_war/Pru_FeService-1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war]`

The service is a soap service without any database component or Hibernate or anything else. Plain vanilla SpringWS

The Pom.xml is as given below.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.test.ipru.api</groupId>
<artifactId>Pru_FeService-1</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>XXXX_FE</name>
<description>Project for FeService</description>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.dozer</groupId>
        <artifactId>dozer</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I have been looking into StackOverflow for days now but none of the solutions seem to work.

Any help would be appreciated very much

Comment: I realize this isn't the exact same situation, but I wonder if it's the same root cause - as both are related to javax.validation under Spring and tWAS 8.5.5: https://dougbreaux.github.io/2018/05/23/springmvc-jsr303-websphere.html

Comment: Hmmm... also, though, your error message refers to spring-context-5. I believe Spring 5 requires Servlet 3.1, which tWAS 8.5 doesn't support.